# Keeping an object's orientation constant while transform: rotate() is applied to it in CSS

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a little animation of the solar system. I used the CSS `transform: rotate(360deg)` to revolve the planets around a fixed center point (the sun). When one of the planets, Saturn, revolves around this point, its orientation naturally follows the path it is going.

I wanted the Saturn object to appear the same while it is orbiting.

[image]

Basically, I want Saturn to appear in that exact same orientation while following the circular path.

I thought CSS `offset-rotate` at 90deg provided exactly what I needed, but my codebase wasn't really suitable for getting the offset paths and using `offset-rotate` (I already tried it, but as my planet objects have visible orbital paths the offset-rotate wasn't applied properly.

This is my source code for the Saturn part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <...>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="solar-system">
            <...>
            <div class="saturn">
                <div class="ring"></div>
                <div class="up"></div>  
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* general config for planets' orbital paths */
.saturn {
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white transparent transparent
    transparent; 
    border-width: 0.1em 0.1em 0 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -55em;
    left: -55em;
    width: 150em;
    height: 150em;
    animation: orbit 5.25s linear infinite; /* stating saturn's orbital 
    period */
}

.saturn::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 18em;
    right: 18em;
    width: 7em;
    height: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(234, 214, 184);
}

@keyframes orbit {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to also rotate `::before`, but in reverse order:

```css
.saturn::before {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ead6b8, transparent);
  animation: orbit 5.25s linear infinite reverse;
}


/* Original styles*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* general config for planets' orbital paths */

.saturn {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 0.1em 0.1em 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -55em;
  left: -55em;
  width: 150em;
  height: 150em;
  animation: orbit 5.25s linear infinite;
  /* stating saturn's orbital 
    period */
}

.saturn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 18em;
  right: 18em;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
}

@keyframes orbit {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="solar-system">
  <div class="saturn">
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <div class="up"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :/ 
The orientation of Saturn is still following its motion even after I rotate ::before in reverse order.

Comment: @Mir I made a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/InSyncWithFoo/pen/rNQVMQV). As you can see, `#saturn::before` doesn't change its orientation. There must be something else in your code that affects it.